# How to estimate REDO phase time during RESTORE

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, restore

I am restoring database now and get it hang on 100% but still going (doing redo phase). I am thinking how to estimate time of completion for this phase. But because SQL have no build-in way to do it, I suppose is it possible to count all modified by commited transactions pages from transaction log, multiple it by 8 to get exact space needed to be modified during the redo phase in data file, and estimate completion time by dividing it on your disk subsystem throughtput?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am thinking how to estimate time of completion for this phase. But because SQL have no build-in way to do it,

If you have not enabled any trace flag you have no option but to look at DMV `sys.dm_exec_requests` and look for column `percent_complete` to gauge how much your restore operation has completed. [Sample script from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152447/is-there-a-sql-script-that-i-can-use-to-determine-the-progress-of-a-sql-server-b)

```
SELECT r.session_id,r.command,CONVERT(NUMERIC(6,2),r.percent_complete)
AS [Percent Complete],CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DATEADD(ms,r.estimated_completion_time,GetDate()),20) AS [ETA Completion Time],
CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),r.total_elapsed_time/1000.0/60.0) AS [Elapsed Min],
CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),r.estimated_completion_time/1000.0/60.0) AS [ETA Min],
CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),r.estimated_completion_time/1000.0/60.0/60.0) AS [ETA Hours],
CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000),(SELECT SUBSTRING(text,r.statement_start_offset/2,
CASE WHEN r.statement_end_offset = -1 THEN 1000 ELSE (r.statement_end_offset-r.statement_start_offset)/2 END)
FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)))
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r WHERE command IN ('RESTORE DATABASE','BACKUP DATABASE')
```

> I am restoring database now and get it hang on 100% but still going (doing redo phase).

Are you sure this is the redo phase, I think this is the UNDO phase and depending on how much VLF's are there in database log file the UNDO process can take time. Of course the whole process of restore can further be delayed if Instant file initialization is not there. You can check using [This script](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2013/10/30/check-for-instant-file-initialization.aspx) whether database is having IFI . If not provide SQL Server service account [perform volume maintenance tasks rights](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779312(v=ws.10).aspx) and this will require a SQL Server service restart

As already pointed by Gameiswar you can enable trace flags to get more information. You can also read [Blog by Bob Dorr](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2008/01/23/how-it-works-what-is-restorebackup-doing/) for more information about internal restore process.

**Please note these are undocumented commands so don't enable it on prod servers.**. These should be used for testing purpose only

```
DBCC TRACEON(3004);

DBCC TRACEON(3014);

DBCC TRACEON(3604);

DBCC TRACEON(3605);

GO
```

Below is what I got when I restored a database with trace flags enabled

```
RestoreDatabase: Database logicalreads

Opening backup set

Restore: Configuration section loaded

Restore: Backup set is open

Restore: Planning begins

Halting FullText crawls on database logicalreads

Dismounting FullText catalogs

X-locking database: logicalreads

Restore: Planning complete

Restore: BeginRestore (offline) on logicalreads

Restore: PreparingContainers

Restore: Containers are ready

Restore: Restoring backup set

Restore: Transferring data to logicalreads

FileHandleCache: 0 files opened. CacheSize: 12

Restore: Data transfer complete on logicalreads

Processed 168 pages for database 'logicalreads', file 'Logicalreads' on file 1.
Processed 1 pages for database 'logicalreads', file 'Logicalreads_log' on file 1.
Restore: Backup set restored

Restore-Redo begins on database logicalreads

Rollforward complete on database logicalreads

Restore: Done with fixups

Restore: Transitioning database to ONLINE

Restore: Restarting database for ONLINE

Restore: Database is restarted

Resuming any halted fulltext crawls

Restore: Writing history records

Writing backup history records

Restore: Done with MSDB maintenance

RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 169 pages in 0.159 seconds (8.303 MB/sec).
RestoreDatabase: Finished
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, both answers are about IFI (which I have enabled). As I got, using these trace flags I would catch only information about IFI slowing down restore, although I need information about REDO phase estimated duration (I am sure about REDO phase, because I am restoring database with NORECOVERY). Why I am so bothered about it, because database files take 11TB (including 0.5TB log), and restoring continues 6 hours already after reaching 100% in percent_complete field of sys.dm_exec_requests.

Comment: How are you restoring the database from SSMS or from other third party tool. Since you have restored it with `NORECOVERY` the database will not recovery and will be in *restoring state*. Can you add the output of query(I gave in answer)  in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant restore REDO phase (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191455%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Run query from SSMS (actualy using agent job). Now it was completed successfully so query do not show anything, but the question stays alive.

Comment: And the answer is you cannot before hand calculate time or see whats actually going on when REDO/UNDO phase is going on while restore is happening. You just cannot predict the time whatever info you can get is using the trace flag after the restore operation completes.

Comment: Can I get a count of modified pages from backup's log and predict time based on my disk performance using received pages size?

Comment: @ko4evneg Maybe, but how useful will that be? How often are you going through a large enough amount of REDO that you have enough time to perform these calculations? How many experiments are you going to go through before you determine your calculations are valid (never mind change anything you're going to do, like just sit and wait until it's finished anyway)? And then you still have no control over what other things might happen (disk or network hiccups, other activity on the box itself, etc.) to throw your estimates way off anyway.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO i  believe you are going for a overkill on which you doesnt have much control.Below are some methods which may help you.

I have restored a database for test and could see below in eventwvr ...

> The database Adventure works is marked as restoring and is in a state that doesnt allows recovery to run.
> starting up database advneture works
> Recovery completed for database Adventure works in 6 seconds (analysis 10 ms,redo 0 ms,undo 5853 ms)

Further if you want to see more info on internals of restore you could use below trace flags .More details on references section

> dbcc traceon(3004, 3605, -1)
> Restore database dbname from disk='c:\test.bak' with stats=1

Instant file initialization helps you in speeding up database restores.if you have not enabled,you should.here is how..

> if your sqlserver service is running as local admin,then permission already exists.
>
> if not,  Grant the permission "Perform Volume Maintenance Tasks",
> This permission can be granted by an administrator through the Local Security Policy tool (Start, All Programs, Administrative Tools) and once granted, SQL Server automatically uses instant initialization.
> **IMPORTANT NOTE:** If this permission is given while SQL Server is running, then SQL Server must be stopped and restarted

**References:**
http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/instant-initialization-what-why-and-how/
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2008/01/23/how-it-works-what-is-restorebackup-doing/